# Is there an “invisible” video player which doesn't show controls at all?

Tags: osx, video, macos, video-player

Is there a video player that I can use on Mac that plays the video without showing the controls at all so that it doesn't look like I'm actually playing a video?

I could still be able to pause and resume the video either when I click on the screen or press spacebar on my keyboard, but I don't want the controls to show up or a "paused" icon to appear at all. Basically, what I need is a totally invisible video player which plays my video file in full screen. I have tried VLC but the controls will always show up whenever I move my cursor onto the screen or pause the screen or any other actions.

I'm thinking of having a video player like this because I'm doing a demo show which I need to play a video but I don't want it to be obvious to my audience that I'm playing a video.

Answer (score 1):

Mplayer in fullscreen mode. In all distributions I've seen space was default for play/pause. OSD can be disabled completely.

Comment: if you want a more active project look at mpv, which is a fork of mplayer. mplayer development is almost stalled, with latest release spring 2019. unless you have a very old hardware, mpv is the best. besides, you won't find a recent binary build for macOS.